# Asus laptop not booting from anything

Tags: windows-10, boot, laptop, bios

Today I woke up and turned my laptop on to start working but it hanged on black screen with white dash blinking so I inserted my windows bootabled usb to repair it but again that black screen.So I reseted the bios settings but nothing helped.I had this problem a month ago that I had to change my hdd . My laptop name is Asus N81VG .
Help Meeee!!!

Comment: Most likely a hardware error. You need a repair-shop to analyze it.

Comment: @harrymc I brought it to repair center, they formatted it hard drive and now I installed windows on it without any errors, They said the partitions were modified.

Comment: This means that something has destroyed the disk. Did they check the SMART info of the disk to see if it's in good shape?

Comment: @harrymc no, They just formatted it and said go home and install windows

Comment: Unfortunate, because according to what you describe, it seems that something is broken.